# Declined flag but thread still closed?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

I found this thread in the Help and Improvement section and flagged it as low quality (which means it goes for a close vote)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29997226/how-to-get-category-link-by-name-in-zencart

Flag was declined (I can only presume to robo-reviewers) but the thread still got closed. Shouldn't there be something to catch this after the fact?

Comment: Was it *disputed* or declined?   Sure, it will be disputed when some horse-shoe thinks the question is salvageable.  Lots and lots of complaints about that already.

Comment: The flag was disputed because of http://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/7912921 and http://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/7912833

Comment: The flag was "disputed" by Community. This is caused by somebody clicking "keep open" or "salvageable" etc. on one of the review queues.

Comment: @HansPassant That would explain a lot

Comment: The first [comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95275/what-is-a-disputed-flag/95277#comment533046_95277) I posted on SE was about this issue. Despite addressing disputed flags after something happens with the post, makes sense to a lot of people, I guess the implementation cost (of time) of such feature is too high.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There shouldn't be anything to catch it after the fact. Disputed clearly means that the triage reviewers completed that review as either "looks ok" or "should be improved". So it's disputed. Which in itself, is not that bad, it's not a declined flag, just disputed.

It's a common issue I personally have had with flagging low quality from HIQ and others have had as well. Disputed flags don't count against flag bans or anything so not a big deal.

You seem to be doing the right things, just need to find a way to improve the accuracy of the triage queue, since many users click "should be improved" instead of "unsalvageable" way too often.

The flags need to be completed at some point, and after it's marked disputed I don't think it should do any more checking, whether it's a day after, a month after, etc.. to see if it did end up being closed. It would be pretty silly to check and re-status user flags like this.